# Warning: Failed to place object at depth 1

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, flex4.5

I am getting a warning when i run my application flash builder burrito.the warning is

> Warning: Failed to place object at depth 1.

Does anyone have any ideas??

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you give some idea of the code you're running?

Comment: @Greg,I am running a flex mobile application for android using flex hero sdk 4.5.0,coming to the coding part i have used mobile and spark components.I am using spark list,i think bcos of that but im not sure

Comment: Can you add some example code pls

Comment: Please - add a code where this occuring, it is very unclear at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I get this too with no indication of where it is happening - it is a continual stream of the error: Warning: Failed to place object at depth 1.

I figured out that it is related to a button movieClip from my library that had a continually cycling keyframe animation in it.

I'm not sure why it happens but if I use a button without the cycling animation, it gets rid of the warning

Comment: i am using move effects through out my application,so you think that may be the reason??

Comment: probably - i dont think it is a problem - it seems like it only happens locally for me.  - also, its a warning not an error

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when trying to embed a swf and use it as the source property of a s:Image control.  Changing the control to the mx:Image component worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve run into this problem using  pdf2swf files in AIR.  I seem to have found a solution, so I thought I would post it here in case anyone else has similar issues.

For the purpose of testing the robustness of my application, I am loading a single-file 500 page pdf-swf into my eReader AIR app.

The problem is that when going from page to page, I see that some of the content from a previous page remains visible.  In the debugger I see a long list of warnings:

```
Warning: Failed to place object at depth 1 
Warning: Failed to place object at depth 2
Etc.
```

I’ve stumbled upon the following work around.  Before going to a new page, I go the following:

```
//  _mainTimeline is the movieClip of the book
if (_mainTimeline.currentFrame != targetFrameNum) {
var chldCnt:int = _mainTimeline.numChildren;
    for (var n:int = 0; n < chldCnt; n++) {
        _mainTimeline.removeChildAt(0);
        if (_mainTimeline.numChildren == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
_mainTimeline.gotoAndStop(targetFrameNum);
}
```

NOTE: I know that it would be shorter to code the iteration as

```
while (_mainTimeline.numChildren > 0) {
    _mainTimeline.removeChildAt(0);
}
```

but I saw the program lockup when I first went to test this, so I added the extra precautionsof only running the loop numChildren times and always checking that there are still children left to remove.  It is probably over-kill, but better safe than sorry.